# Windows 7 Taskbar Auto-Hide

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

I have set the windows 7 Taskbar to auto-hide however some of the time an application will tell the Taskbar something new is going on. This causes the Taskbar to light up, and block the window underneath until l I give it attention.  Is there a registry tweak to keep the Taskbar from seeking attention?

Comment: What do you mean by "something new is going on"...currently i'm auto hiding it..when a new program opens...taskbar will still be hidden though . (note: i didn't add a comment cause my rep still below 50)

Comment: Just as a workaround: killing explorer.exe via task manager and then starting it again worked for me.

Comment: @VincentAlex: For the bounty, are we still on Windows 7? Or on Windows 10/11?

Comment: Win7 please, ForeGroundFlashCount=1 doesn't seem to be working for many of us.

Comment: Don't need or ever want Win 10/11  Win7 can be super fast and friendly if you make it

Comment: Move your taskbar to the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're so annoyed by the Windows 7 Taskbar, why not getting rid of it altogether? :)

> Aviassin Taskbar Eliminator is a great
>   utility which will simply and
>   efficiently remove the taskbar from
>   Windows XP or Vista.
>
> With just the click of a button or a
>   hotkey, the taskbar is disabled from
>   any side of the screen, providing the
>   freedom to use any dock application,
>   increase computer security, or allow
>   all sorts of Windows customizations.
>   The taskbar can be toggled on and off
>   in real-time, providing the
>   flexibility to quickly view the
>   taskbar to perform an action.
>
> The application interface is simple
>   and easy to understand, allowing it to
>   be used by even the most novice of
>   users. Simply press and hold
>   Control+Alt+T to bring up the
>   Preferences window, from which all
>   options can be adjusted. Press and
>   hold Alt + T to immediately show or
>   hide the taskbar directly.

[image]

Supported Operating Systems:

Windows 98
Windows 2000
Windows XP
Windows Vista
**Windows 7 Beta & Release Candidate**

**[Download](http://www.aviassin.com/taskbareliminator)**

*Aviassin Taskbar Eliminator is freeware and portable.*

when you click 'Hide Taskbar' it will disappear but the start orb remains visible, however, if you set the the taskbar to 'Auto Hide' before eliminating the taskbar, it works like a charm. the start orb will not appear if you hit the bottom of the screen, ONLY if you press the windows key.

[image]

... and then use **[VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html)** to toggle conveniently between open applications and folders.

[image]

Comment: I like the Windows 7 task-bar actually. Just not how it likes to come out and stay out.

Comment: ah well ... just an idea :)

Comment: Yeah, it's not like anyone in the world will use Alt+T in any program ever. Like opening a menu starting with the letter T... what is it we used to say in 2002? Oh yeah, "bigfatlol". Memories :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own application which one forcibly hides the taskbar if mouse is not hovering...

http://hotfile.com/links/115779822/57566f8/HideTaskbar.zip

VB6 runtime files may be needed. Works on XP, Vista and 7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can disable the taskbar from flashing. I have read that TuneUp utilites has an option to do that.

If you want to control the number of times the taskbar flashes, then do the following:

1. Open regedit and Navigate to:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\CONTROLPANEL\DESKTOP
2. In the right pane, right click on
   ForeGroundFlashCount
3. Click on Modify, and select Decimal.
4. Change the Value to a higher number to however many flashes you want.
   1 will give you a single flash.
   0 will give you indefinite flashes.
5. Restart the computer to apply the changes.

Comment: I like this, but after the flashing is done the taskbar stays up.

Comment: You meant "infinite", not "indefinite".

Comment: Nothing on computers are infinite. 
in·def·i·nite
/ˌinˈdef(ə)nət/
Learn to pronounce
adjective
lasting for an unknown or unstated length of time.

Answer (score 0):

Head on over to [**Windows SevenForums**](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/44913-disabletaskbarontop-disable-taskbar-always-top.html) for a possible workaround to this issue.

There is a tool hosted on the forum which tells the taskbar not to shrink out of view but to simply go to the back of the screen.  32-bit and 64-bit flavours are available.  It is a run-on-demand program, so nothing to install.  Simply log off and back on again if you don't think it's for you.  No harm done.

Once it is running, other applications can be dragged over the taskbar which will then stay on top of it, regardless of whether the taskbar wants attention or not.

[image]

To immediately get the taskbar back into view, either press the Windows key or click on a part of the taskbar that isn't hidden underneath other applications.

It is far from ideal, but does appear to be one of the best fixes that other people with the exact same problem have managed to get their hands on.

Comment: I'd rather not mess with the task-bar on top properties.

Comment: If you bring up the taskbar properties, you can unselect "Keep the taskbar on top of other windows" and achieve the same thing.

Comment: @Software Monkey - that feature was removed in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible solutions :

- Ensure that all the icons in the traybar are visible, as icons
  that are hidden (available still via the arrow-icon) may not be hidden
  even if the traybar itself is hidden.
- Completely [disable balloon notifications](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-all-notification-balloons-in-windows-vista/) via regedit in
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`,
  create a new 32-bit DWORD named `EnableBalloonTips` and set its value to `0`.

Comment: Cheers, I already disabled balloon, but sometimes an app starts (mostly clover tabs), stays highlighted on taskbar (not even flashing), thus keeps taskbar visible (unable to auto hide), until I click on it, which is annoying. Icons don't fill up entire taskbar, so I think they are visible. Weird UI bug.

Comment: I didn't mean taskbar icons, but traybar icons. The traybar is found to the right of the taskbar.