# How can I disable flashing icons on Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, windows-registry

I set my Windows 7 taskbar to auto-hide. However, sometimes when a program changes or something new happens in a program, the taskbar will show its self, and its respective taskbar icon will begin flashing orange.

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

To make the taskbar hide again, I have click on the program before I can go back to what I was doing.

Anyways, I personally find this **very** annoying, and would love to find a way to either:

1. Prevent the taskbar from having such alerts.
2. Prevent the taskbar from showing its self when it has such alerts.

I've searched around quite a bit, and really only found answers to this for XP.

I've also found another [Stack Exchange Question](https://superuser.com/questions/99952/windows-7-taskbar-auto-hide) looking for the same thing for Windows 7. However, none of the answers to the question were really what I'm looking for. I'm not looking to [hide](https://superuser.com/questions/99952/windows-7-taskbar-auto-hide/109181#109181) the taskbar, or [control the number of flashes](https://superuser.com/questions/99952/windows-7-taskbar-auto-hide/109570#109570).

However, [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/99952/windows-7-taskbar-auto-hide/275278#275278) seems to be what I'm looking for, so I downloaded and tried out the program. It works perfectly, other than the fact that the start menu icon is always shown, regardless of the taskbar being set to auto-hide.

So, any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

#### Steps to disable flashing icon on Taskbar - Windows 7

1. Click the **Start** icon
2. Type in `regedit`
3. Select **regedit** from the top of the result
4. Go to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
5. Editing `ForegroundFlashCount`

   1. Find `ForegroundFlashCount`
   2. Double click `ForegroundFlashCount`
   3. Replace the *value* for **Value Data** with `1`
6. Editing `ForegroundLockTimeout`

   1. Find `ForegroundLockTimeout`
   2. Double click `ForegroundLockTimeout`
   3. Replace the *value* for **Value Data** with `0`
7. Reboot

This is the way to do it without any 3rd-party applications. The steps are in detail steps to help both experienced and non-experienced users. If you want to undo these changes, repeat the steps above using the original values: `ForegroundFlashCount` is `7`; `ForegroundLockTimeout` is `30d40`.

*Disclaimer : You **should** always [backup your registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows) before editing your registry.*

Comment: ForegroundLockTimeout was already 0 before I touched it

Comment: Didn't work for me, after changing these settings the default behavior persisted.

Comment: In each DWORD dialog, do we leave Base as Hexadecimal or Decimal?

Comment: @PaulyGlott For values less than or equal to 9, it does not matter. If you were to revert to the original values, you would have to use Hexadecimal for the ForegroundLockTimeout value (30d40).

Comment: You actually do not need to reboot, changes should appear immediately.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I'll remove my downvote if you fix this.

Comment: Doesn't work for me too, on Windows 10

Comment: Seems like this answer is not working for many, what's the alternative?

Answer (score -3):

Try the free option given above. If it doesn't work, [TuneUp Utilities 2011](http://www.tune-up.com/download/) has a feature to disable this:

[image]

It's not free, but they have a 15 day trial (so you can ensure it *does* work).

Comment: I just tried out this program. Unfortunately, after using this setting and restarting my computer, the flashing still exists: http://i.imgur.com/d2g63.png

Comment: All this tool does is set the registry keys mentioned in the top answer. So what's the point?