# Disable new window taskbar blinking

Tags: windows, windows-vista

You know that annoying orange taskbar blinking? I use Pidgin (among other programs), and I hate it when my taskbar appears with the orange blinking when I am in the middle of something.

My taskbar is on auto-hide and set up to the left side of the screen.

I cannot click the window I am working to make it overlap the taskbar. (I could disable "Keep taskbar on top of other windows", but it completely hides the taskbar then.)

---

Ideal scenario:

- Orange light blinks, and I click somewhere (i.e. my maximized window) to hide the taskbar again.

Answer (score 4):

In Pidgin, `Tools --> Plugins`, disabling the *Message Notification* plugin would stop Pidgin from flashing the taskbar.

UPDATE: see [How can I disable flashing icons on Windows 7 taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/316879/how-can-i-disable-flashing-icons-on-windows-7-taskbar) -- This may also work on Vista.

Comment: Actually, it already is disabled...