# Disable flashing icons windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Is there a way to disable the flashing orange icons in the taskbar (under the application icon itself) in Windows 8?

I'm fine with it turning orange, just the pulsating orange effect is extremely distracting.

Thanks in advance.

The solution for Windows 7 in the proposed duplicate answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/316879/how-can-i-disable-flashing-icons-on-windows-7-taskbar) does **not** apply to Windows 8

Comment: You mean when the Taskbar icons flash to alert you to something going on in a program that's hidden?  If that's what you mean, it's SUPPOSED to be distracting, as it's an Alert. :)  If that's not what you mean, then I have no idea what you're referring to by "orange icon under the application's icon"; please edit your question to describe it better, and/or include a screen shot of what you're talking about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable flashing icons on Windows 7 taskbar?](http://superuser.com/questions/316879/how-can-i-disable-flashing-icons-on-windows-7-taskbar)

Comment: Yes it's similar, but that advice no longer applies to windows 8. I am talking about when they flash to alert you yeah. I just find it a bit too obtrusive. Just the color change to orange would suffice for me. Thanks

Comment: So you tried the solutions offered and they don't work?

Comment: Yeah, those parameters no longer exist in the windows 8 registry