# How to disable flashing icons in Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar, notifications

My question is the same as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/316879/how-can-i-disable-flashing-icons-on-windows-7-taskbar) but for Windows 10 instead of Windows 7.

Is there a way to stop taskbar icons from flashing orange to get my attention? I find it very distracting. I have tried changing the registry values mentioned in the linked question to no success.

Comment: See if this helps....http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-flashing-taskbar-buttons-windows

Answer (score 5):

Did some research on the matter, and there are two things I found. You must complete both, and then restart, to eliminate flashing icons.

1. Right-click on an empty area of the taskbar and select "Taskbar settings." Scroll down to the "Show badges on taskbar buttons" setting and disable it.
2. Open Regedit.

   - Set `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundFlashCount` to 0
   - Set `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundLockTimeout` to 0
3. Then restart Windows to make sure the registry changes take effect

Hope this helps and you will find a solution for your problem with this :)

Source 1: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-stop-icons-from-appearing-and-flashing-in/fd405a8b-750a-4c8f-a37c-165db509988b
leading to

Source 2: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-flashing-taskbar-buttons-windows

Comment: This works! Thanks! Step 2 I had tried before, but disabling the badges (step 1) fixed it for me. Hope you don't mind, but I submitted an edit to your answer to clarify both 1 and 2 need to be completed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ... or at least I thought it fixed it. I might have accidentally focused the window while testing or something, because now I'm getting flashing icons despite double-checking the above 3 steps.

Comment: For some reason this does not work. For now there is nothing that can stop flashing icons. MS is aware of this issue although there never has been no update. For now the only workaround is to either disable notifications from settings or if you're using something like Teams or Outlook, set them up to run in background so that you can peacefully close those apps and access them from taskbar. At least the flashes stop.

Comment: Tried for three times: not working.

Comment: @Shiv_90 How can I disable notification from setting?

Comment: @Shiv_90 I already turn off the "Get notifications from apps and other senders"

Answer (score -2):

Type Settings on your search bar.
Click on systems.
Select notifications and actions.
Disable all the notifications on the screen.

Comment: Notifications are not the same thing as icon flashing. Flashing is used by some apps when new activity occurs and is an old technique from before notification balloons were added in xp.